# null pointer exception hibernate on creating sessionfactory

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

Hi i trying to write my first Hibernate program,
its giving an error while instantiating the session factory.
I'm using hibernate 5.0.4 & java 8 & eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1) & oracle 11g.

MainClass is:

```
public class MainMethod {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SampleClass s = new SampleClass();
    s.setId(1);
    s.setValue("Value_1");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(s);
    session.getTransaction().commit();      
}
}
```

the hibernate.cfg.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mndb11g</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">temp_p</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">temp_p</property>
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">temp_p</property>

  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <mapping class="com.h.SampleClass.SampleClass"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Its giving an exception at

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

The exception stack trace is

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:173)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:348)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:119)
    at com.h.MainMethod.main(MainMethod.java:19)
```

Can anyone please help to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This could happen due to several reasons.

- May be the Entity cannot be found. In your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file the entity is mentioned as `com.h.SampleClass.SampleClass`
  Please double check the class name and the package name.
- Make sure that the hibernate libraries are added as user libraries. Not system libraries. [More info](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1476143/#msg_1476143)

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes my package is com.h.SampleClass & my class is SampleClass. & but i've added them as system libraries.. changed to user libraries. Working perfect. thanks :)

Comment: This works for me. I created a standalone java project and try to import Hibernate libraries as user libraries but selected 'System libraries' checkbox. Error disappeared after unchecking the 'System libraries' 
 checkbox

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like hibernate.cfg.xml is not on your classpath when the code runs. If you are using maven put it in src/main/resources.